# Write integration test for rest_pre_serve_request

Tags: unit-tests

I have a method that is hooked to the `rest_api_init`

```
  /**
   * Set allowed headers for the rest request
   */
  public function set_allowed_rest_headers() {

    remove_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', 'rest_send_cors_headers' );

    add_filter(
      'rest_pre_serve_request', function( $value ) {
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . esc_url_raw( 'some url pulled from options' ) );
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, PATCH' );
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );

        return $value;
      }
    );
  }
```

I want to test this using `phpunit`.

I've created a test case

```
<?php
/**
 * Class Test_Admin
 *
 * @package test
 */

/**
 * Class that tests the REST functionality.
 */
class Test_Rest extends WP_UnitTestCase {
  /**
   * Initial set up for the test
   */
  public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();

    /**
     * Global $wp_rest_server variable
     *
     * @var WP_REST_Server $wp_rest_server Mock REST server.
     */
    global $wp_rest_server;

    $wp_rest_server = new \WP_REST_Server();
    $this->server   = $wp_rest_server;

    do_action( 'rest_api_init' );

  }

  /**
   * Tear down after test ends
   */
  public function tearDown() {
    parent::tearDown();

    global $wp_rest_server;
    $wp_rest_server = null;

  }

  /**
   * Test if the REST API headers are set
   *
   * @since 1.1.0
   */
  public function test_allowed_rest_headers() {

    $request  = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/posts' );
    $response = $this->server->dispatch( $request );

    $this->assertEquals( 200, $response->get_status() );

    $headers  = $request->get_headers();
    $headers2 = $response->get_headers();
    error_log( print_r( $headers, true ) );
    error_log( print_r( $headers2, true ) );
  }
}
```

The assertion that response is `200` is passing, but the `error_log` returns nothing for the request headers, and

```
Array
(
    [X-WP-Total] => 0
    [X-WP-TotalPages] => 0
)
```

For the response headers. But I'd need to test that the `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers are set correctly.

How to do that (besides manually setting them during the unit test)?

I've tried calling the `set_allowed_rest_headers()` method inside the test, but nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The question actually has nothing specific to wordpress, but maybe it is worth answering.

There is simply no code of your own in that sample that can be/is worth testing, therefor there isn't much to unit test.

Lets look at the details. `add_filter` is integration with core code, `remove_filter` is integration with core code and `header` is integration with PHP core. If you remove all of those lines you are left with zero code.

Or to say it differently, the three functions mentions above are changing the global state and not your internal state, and while you might be able to construct a relevant test, in the end you are going to be testing them much more than testing your own code.

What you need here is an integration test, set a wordpress instance with your code, send an api request and inspect the result.

Comment: I meant integration test, not unit test, since this is the code from the plugin. I'm using `wp-cli`'s [scaffold](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/scaffold/plugin-tests/).

Comment: You need to decide what is it that you are testing. If you test the way the whole application is functioning than you need to do it from the outside. As I said for the specific code you showed there is basically nothing else to test, and any test oriented abstraction you might do will only result in needlessly complex code.

Comment: What do you mean 'from the outside'? I'm using WordPress in a decoupled way. The front end app is communicating with it via REST API. I'm setting the headers for any rest requests because I need to avoid CORS issues. By setting the headers on `rest_pre_serve_request ` I'm modifying the request. So basically I need to have an automated test proving that it works (not my requirement, clients). I know that it works because I've tested it with the frontend app. I just need to have a code coverage :/

Comment: If you need to test how the plugin behaves, than the only thing is to test it from outside of wordpress. For proper test of what you need it is not enough to test that segment in isolation, because maybe that code is never included. So again the question is what is it that you want to test, if it is the end result of sending a request and getting the result than you have to do it from **outside of wordpress**

Answer (score 0):

If what you're indeed trying to do is to verify that the WordPress Core continues to behave correctly after future upgrades and that your hooked method is triggered and that the headers are thus set on the response, then I have a suggestion.

First, you're going to want to make sure you've some way of debugging this application.  I suggest breakpoints, but it looks like you're partial to print statements.  Either works, but if you use print statements, then be sure to print some dummy data to verify that you can tell the difference between an empty variable or a misconfigured logging level.

Given a debugging method, there's a few places to hook into.  First, make sure that your "rest_api_init" hooked function is in fact being called.  Print at the start of it and verify you see your message.  Assuming you do, then the rabbit hole goes on.

In my version of WordPress, line 494 of `class-wp-rest-server.php` has your `rest_pre_serve_request` filter being triggered.  Debug that you're in fact triggering that line with your test invocation -- you should be able to print before, then see your attached function fire, and then also print after.

Assuming you're hitting that line, and that your attached function is triggered, note that the rest (haha no pun intended) of that core method does not include any calls to `$this->send_headers(...)` so I assume at this point your `headers(...)` call (being core PHP code) should be working.

If not, note that just above on line 474 we see `$headers = $result->get_headers();` so looking up the docs for [WP_Rest_Response](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_response/) we see it extends [WP_HTTP_Response](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_http_response/__construct/) which has the ability to set headers in the constructor and also directly with [set_headers](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_http_response/set_headers/).  From here, you can create a middleware for your responses which set the headers for you, in a worst-case scenario.

Further digging into the core file can help you understand why your `headers(...)` calls as-is do not work.